# Sencha Touch NestedList - Right To Left

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, right-to-left, nested-lists

Trying to RTLify (Convert to Right-to-Left) a sencha touch NestedList.

1. How do I change the default Animation direction when clicking an item?
2. How do I place the back button on the top-right side instead of top-left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. `nestedlist.getLayout().setAnimation({type:'slide',direction:'right'});`
2. add this in your nestedlist config `backButton:{ui:'forward', align:'right'}`